# Clone GitHub repository in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to clone a GitHub repository into the newest release of VSCode (1.3.0). Can this be done natively or do I need to add an extension or additional binary?

I've also searched for a blog article and coming up empty handed so any guidance would be appreciated

Paul

Comment: what's the problem in opening a the bash prompt and writing `git clone yourrepo`?

Comment: That was plan b or c

Answer (score 62):

Starting from the 1.8 (November) update of vscode you can now clone your Git repository from within the vscode.

You can execute it from the **Command Palette**. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) and search for `Git: Clone`. Confirm the command and paste the repository url.

Answer (score 1):

There are now two programmatic ways how to clone a repository. VS Code handles the `vscode://` protocol now, so you could clone a repository by clicking on a link somewhere on a web page

For example, clicking on the following link invokes VS Code, lets you select a folder on your disk, fetches the code and finally suggests to open that location as a workspace.

vscode://vscode.git/clone?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fvscode-extension-samples

Alternatively, if you are trying to trigger the cloning from an extension code, use the built-in VS Code command `git.clone` with the repo url as the only argument.

```
import { commands} from 'vscode';

commands.executeCommand("git.clone", "https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples");
```

Both seem to do the same as the *Git: Clone* command mentioned by Jakub.

Answer (score 1):

Even faster, with VSCode 1.58 (June 2021), for GitHub repositories with the "`Open in Visual Studio Code`" badge.
While the announcement [was removed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/commit/11380c75c6a91caa597d2573b676cd1698a55004), it was replaced with [Visual Studio Code for the Web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web).

The [VSCode Web "Opening a project" section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web#_opening-a-project) mentions:

> You can navigate to a project repository directly from a URL, following the scheme: `https://vscode.dev/SOURCE/ORG/REPO`.
> Using the VS Code repo as an example, this would look like: https://vscode.dev/github/microsoft/vscode.

And [issue 128813](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128813#issuecomment-943125631) suggests:

> I suggest we just use shields.io for this:
>
> `https://img.shields.io/static/v1?logo=visualstudiocode&label=&message=Open%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20Code&labelColor=2c2c32&color=007acc&logoColor=007acc`
>
> [image: badge from shields]

So the mardown would be:

`[![Open in VS Code](https://img.shields.io/static/v1?logo=visualstudiocode&label=&message=Open%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20Code&labelColor=2c2c32&color=007acc&logoColor=007acc)](https://vscode.dev/SOURCE/ORG/REPO)`

Comment: it's not clear how to add this badge, no snippet given

Comment: @Suncatcher Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have updated/rewritten the answer to describe how that feature evolved, and include the markdown snippet you would need.

Comment: @Suncatcher I just updated my [own project `README` to include such a badge](https://github.com/VonC/gitcred/blob/b2c5494297d36d19de2c8bd1af763e0932424446/README.md). It does work (provided you allow vscode.dev to sign in to your GitHub account)

Answer (score 0):

If you by native means in the GUI of the application, the answer is no. Though there is an open issue regarding this on their Github repository https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9085 it doesn't look like they have the interest to implement it.

Even so, you can of course still clone a repository in your Terminal of choice and then handle the rest of your git functionality through the editor when you're working with the project.

Comment: Thanks looks like the current situation is no native integration and do it outside the UI. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

I use github Desktop (https://desktop.github.com/) for both my github repos and gitlab repos